# SigmaJs Is it possible to change attribute of a node/link of an existing graph sigma js? Like i want to change color of a link/node .?

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

SigmaJs Is it possible to change attribute of a node/link of an existing graph sigma js? Like i want to change color of a link/node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible, you just have to change any attribute on the sigma graph object. AFter you have to call the refresh function :
s.refresh().

This is an example where 's' is your sigma instance:

```
// NB : using jquery function each 
$.each(s.graph.edges(), function(index, edge) {
  edge.color = 'blue';
});

s.refresh();
```